# Is there a way to use Bluebird's Promise.each concurrently?

Tags: concurrency, promise, bluebird

Bluebird has a nice function called `Promise.map` that lets you pass in an extra argument for the amount of concurrent operations.

e.g.

```
yield Promise.map arrayOfThings, coroutine (thing) ->
  newThing = yield thing.operate()
  database.set newThing
, concurrency: 500
```

However, `Promise.map` will keep an array of whatever `database.set newThing` returns in memory for all of `arrayOfThings`. I'd rather not store all of that in memory as it bogs down my server. Optimally, I would want to replace `Promise.map` with `Promise.each` so it doesn't store the returned values in memory. Unfortunately this is super slow because `Promise.each` is not concurrent.

Is there any way I can change my code to make it work like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, at the moment `Promise.each` doesn't actually not allocate the array. There is an open issue for this - I'm assigned and I'd like to apologize - I'm not in front of a dev box and have been abroad. I'll try to fix this soon.

Second of all - no. There is no such functionality at the moment. `Promise.each` was created in order to precisely run things sequentially. A pull request *might* be entertained and it shouldn't be too hard to implement on top of `PromiseArray`. We just haven't really seen the use case before.

Meanwhile you can use `Promise.map`.