# Difference between map and each on Promise bluebird

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, bluebird

What would be the difference between doing these two things:

```
Promise.map(myValues, async myValue => {
  const owner = await findOwner(myValue);
  return Promise.all([sendMessage(owner), sendMessageSpecific(owner)]);
})
```

and

```
Promise.each(myValues, async myValue => {
  const owner = await findOwner(myValue);
  sendMessage(owner)
  sendMessageSpecific(owner)
})
```

I know both each and map return a Promise, but I can't figure out what would be the difference from a running perspective. It looks like with `each` there is no chance for concurrency, one promise happens after the other one, but I'm missing any other big differences between these two code snippets?

Comment: one difference is concurrency - but I gathered that from reading the doucmenation, same as you - also in the documentation, with `each` *If all of the iterations resolve successfully, Promise.each resolves to the original array unmodified.* - not so with map, because maping maps

Comment: Omitting the `Promise.all` call from `sendMessage(owner)` and `sendMessageSpecific(owner)` in the second snippet just makes it not work. This has nothing to do with `each` vs `map` though.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28737038/1048572, https://stackoverflow.com/a/40408505/1048572